# case insensitive replacement in python using re

Tags: python, python-re

with this code

```
import re

str = 'hi my name is Alice'
print(re.sub(str, 'hi', 'hello', re.IGNORECASE))
```

I got `hello`

I expect it would be `hello my name is Alice`

What's wrong here?

Comment: Did you check [what arguments `re.sub` takes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)? (Particularly, what order they come in?)

Answer (score 1):

From [pydocs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), the signature of re.sub() is

`re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

so your code should be

```
print(re.sub('hi', 'hello', str, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```